# Card not saving for later use in Stripe React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments

In my application i'm tokenizing the card details with CardField values. Here's how my UI component looks like:

```js
<CardField
    postalCodeEnabled={false}
    placeholder={{
        number: '4242 4242 4242 4242',
    }}
    cardStyle={{
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        textColor: '#000000',
    }}
    style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: 50,
        marginVertical: 30,
    }}
    onCardChange={(cardDetails) => {
        setCard(cardDetails);
    }}
/>
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.continue} onPress={addCardDetails}>
  <Text>
    Pay
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Now i am tokenizing the card info and trying to add the card for later use. Here's what i've done.

```js
    const addCardDetails = async () => {

        const token = await createToken({
            type: 'Card',
            currency: 'usd',
            address: {
                country: 'US',
            },
            name: 'cardName',
        })
        const card = {"card": {
            "source": {
              "source": token.token.id
            }
          }
        }
        await fetch('${API}/payment/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'x-access-token': accessToken,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                card
            }),
        }).then(res => {
            res.json().then(response => {
                console.info(response, 'response');
            });
        });
        
    }
```

Now, the createToken is giving me ID but when i use that ID to store card for later use, it doesn't add to the card array. What do i need to do to add card for later use.

Comment: "but when i use that ID to store card for later use" Where's the code where you do that?

Comment: it's there in the function. token.token.id is the ID i was talking about. @karllekko

Comment: All that code does is create a credit card token. It doesn't attempt to save it to a customer for future use or charge it or anything  else. Maybe your backend server code(${API}/payment/) does that but you didn't share the code of that backend.

Comment: my card is not being created in stripe backend. That's what i'm saying. I need to do that. My backend isn't storing anything which is why i didn't share that code. The card need to be validated on the client side and add on the stripe backend. What is the way to do that? @karllekko

Comment: The way to do it is to follow the current guide https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet where you'd confirm a SetupIntent client side, which saves the card, you wouldn't use these legacy approaches of creating a token and posting it your backend server. If you are using that legacy approach, then your backend code which you refuse to share is important though since that is where the saving actually happens in legacy integrations. But putting that aside, you should replace what you have and use SetupIntents.